# How to sync two folders with Gradle?

Tags: groovy, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I need keep folder `inside` synced with a folder called `outside`. The `inside` folder needs to be an exact copy of the `outside` folder - all subdirectories, files, etc.

The `Copy` task works great, except that it will only overwrite files - it does not delete files that are still in the `inside` folder if those files are no longer in the `outside` folder.

Right now I am using the `Delete` task, which the `Copy` task depends on. The `Delete` task fails every other build, with the below error. The `inside` folder does get deleted, but the new files from the `Copy` task are not copied over.

```
Error:(117) A problem occurred evaluating project ':android'.
> Cannot convert the provided notation to a File or URI: true.
  The following types/formats are supported:
    - A String or CharSequence path, e.g 'src/main/java' or '/usr/include'
    - A String or CharSequence URI, e.g 'file:/usr/include'
    - A File instance.
    - A URI or URL instance.
```

I am guessing this happens because of some type of Gradle caching issue - how do I fix this, or design the process better? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

looks like there's a big difference between using a tasks parameter to declare task type/dependencies and doing so in the task method body.

Something like this worked great

```
task deleteFiles(type: Delete) {
    delete destinationHtmlFolder
}

task copyFiles(dependsOn: tasks.withType(Copy)){
    println "copying all files"
}
```